# Sum land area grid based on land class grid in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix, grid

I have two grids of equal shape, one is for land class and the other is land area.

Examples:
Land class

```
[[1 4 3],  
 [3 2 3],  
 [1 3 3]]
```

Land area

```
[[0.3 0.8 2.0],  
 [5.0 1.5 0.5],  
 [0.1 1.0 3.2]]
```

I need to sum up land area based on land class, and it would be delightful to print something like this:

```
1 0.4  
2 1.5  
3 11.7  
4 0.8
```

The only module I've imported is numpy, and I would like to avoid importing others if possible.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
import numpy as np

lc=np.array([[1, 4, 3],
            [3, 2, 3],
            [1, 3, 3]])

la=np.array([[0.3, 0.8, 2.0],
            [5.0, 1.5, 0.5],
            [0.1, 1.0 ,3.2]])



calc_areas = []

for v in np.unique(lc):
    print(v, np.sum(la[lc==v]))
    calc_areas.append([v, np.sum(la[lc==v])])


calc_areas.sort(key=lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)
print("Max area", calc_areas[0])
```

Gives:

```
1 0.4
2 1.5
3 11.7
4 0.8

('Max area', [3, 11.699999999999999])
```

Comment: How would you print an additional line that indicates the class with the largest area?  So, in this case it would simply print out a 3 (since it's the largest land class).

Comment: @kwikstrom You can sort the areas. I amended the example.